# Guardar un archivo en una carpeta del usuario

Tags: c#, archivo

Quiero guardar un archivo de texto en la carpeta de documentos del usuario, pero no se como acceder a esa carpeta sin poner algo como `"C:\Users\Emmanuel\Documentos\"` porque logicamente eso solo funcionara en mi computadora, quiero asi ago como `"C:\\localhost\Documents\"`. Si hago justo lo último me crea una carpeta llamada `localhost` y otra `Documents`.

Comment: Porque no guardas el archivo en la carpeta del programa?

Comment: Me gustaría aprender a hacerlo de otra manera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres guardar un archivo dentro de las carpetas de un usuario, por ejemplo documentos, imagene, etc. sin conocer el nombre del usuario puedes hacerlo de dos formas:
1. Con la variable %USERPROFILE% de windows:

```
string sharedFolder = @"%USERPROFILE%\fichero.txt";
var filePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(sharedFolder);
File.WriteAllText(filePath, "texto de test");
```

2. Con la variable userprofile de C#:

   ```
       string basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
       var filePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(basePath)+@"\fichero.txt";
       File.WriteAllText(filePath, "texto de test");
   ```

A base path le tienes que concatenar la carpeta que quieras por ejemplo Documents para la carpeta documentos.

Saludos

Comment: Para unir carpetas o carpetas y el archivo deberias usar `string filePath = Path.Combine(basePath, "fichero.txt");` asi te evitas el problema de decidir si pones `\` o no cuando unes

Answer (score 1):

Conocer de forma dinamica la carpeta del usuario se utiliza

[Environment.SpecialFolder](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netcore-3.1)

```
string docFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

Partamos de la base que algo como `c:\\localhost` no existe, ya que `c:\` hace referencia a una unidad de disco, mientras que `localhost` se refiere a una localizacion de red

`localhost` es lo mismo que poner `127.0.0.1`

[¿Qué es localhost o IP 127.0.0.1 y para qué se utiliza?](https://computerhoy.com/noticias/internet/que-es-localhost-ip-127001-que-utiliza-48046)

Si tienes una carpeta compartida en la red se puede acceder a esta si usas `\\localhost\`

Si tienes permisos de escritura en esta carpeta compartida podrias usar `\\localhost\SharedFolder`

[Como compartir carpeta Windows 10](https://www.profesionalreview.com/2018/11/03/compartir-carpeta-windows-10/#Compartir_carpeta_Windows_10_y_acceder_a_ella)

entonces si defines

```
string sharedFolder = @"\\localhost\SharedFolder\nombreFile.txt";
File.WriteAllText(sharedFolder, "texto de test");
```

se creara el archivo en esta carpeta compartida en la red

Pero en este caso si compartes a la red la carpeta ´Documentos´ sera lo mismo que uses `C:\Users\Emmanuel\Documentos` o `\\localhost\Documentos` si lo haces desde la misma PC

Comment: Lo de localhost era solo un ejemplo, quiero poder guardar un archivo en la carpeta Documentos del usuario, pero sin conocer el usuario previamente

Comment: edite la respuesta, puse como recuperas de forma dinamica la carpeta folder del usuario

Comment: igual no habia entendido que era un ejemplo lo que planteabas, porque usaste `localhost` con lo cual estabas mezclando conceptos de red con carpetas local, si era un ejemplo algo habias planteado de forma incorrecta por eso es que en mi respuesta aclare esa diferencia